# Angular view ngFor not displaying observable collection after it has been updated in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx

I have an Angular 9 application using NGRX that for the most part uses observables/subjects and the assync pipe.

I have a navbar component that has the following HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let menuItem of navbarMenuItems | async">
      <a id="{{ menuItem.id }}" [routerLink]="menuItem.routerLink" class="nav-link">
        <span><i class="icon" [className]="menuItem.iconClass"></i>{{ menuItem.translationKey | translate }}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The navbarMenuItems is an observable array that I attach in my component ngOnInit method:

```
this.navbarMenuItems = this.navbarService.getNavbarMenuItems();
```

The NavbarService looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class NavbarService {

  public navbarMenuItems = new Subject<NavbarActionModel[]>();

  constructor(
  ) { }

  updateNavbarMenuItems(items: NavbarActionModel[]) {
    this.navbarMenuItems.next(items);
  }

  getNavbarMenuItems(): Observable<any> {
    return this.navbarMenuItems.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Everything works perfect when calling the NavbarService updateNavbarMenuItems() method from any other component (i.e. the navbar updates and shows the actions that you send it).

However, if I call the updateNavbarMenuItems() in the NavbarComponent (i.e. the one with the HTML) ngOnInit method the HTML doesn't update. **BUT** if I call the update method in the ngAfterViewInit() method they do appear.

A colleague of mine helped me fix the issue and told me it's because of a race condition where the *ngFor isn't rendered in time, which seems to be right. However, this seems really strange to me and I feel like I must be doing something else wrong and there is another bug in my code/best practice not followed if anyone can help?

Comment: As long as you update the value after you ~create~ *set* `this.navbarMenuItems` (within your navbar component) the Observable stream should update properly.

Comment: I do (or at least I think I do going through the debug tools) and that's why I think my issue might not be related to the rendering! This feels similar to so many other things I do that work (i.e. setting ngFor collections to observables).

Comment: I'd personally not use the `async` pipe. If you just subscribe to that Subject in your component, and assigning there the result, it should work fine.

Comment: Why not use the aync pipe? This feels like a cleaner solution to me but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm with Jacopo for this in general. I find the the async pipe is *quarky* to say the least (especially in regards to timing in general). When you use a subscription to a subject you have a lot more control over the specific timing of all rendering (and it's easier to make updates based on those changes).

Comment: Also, you can try to use a `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`. Another option would be to initialize `navbarMenuItems = of(EMPTY)` to ensure you aren't hitting DOM rendering issues.

Comment: Interestingly enough a replay subject solves the issue too. I don't really understand why!

Comment: When you use ngrx why, you do not use selectors?

Comment: @Stefan if you manually subscribe instead of using the async pipe you have to unsusbribe too (not a big problem) but it's one less thing to worry about/forget and it also reduces code to use the async pipe. That's why I like them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subject` is not returning any value on `Subscription`, it triggers only new value emitted by `.next(value)`.

`BehaviorSubject` is returning also last emitted value on each new `Subscription`.

In this case, you should use `BehaviorSubject` to be sure that value will be emitted a new time when `async` pipe will subscribe to observable.

Check this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eu8xtt-so-60564981).

You can see that if we simulate a delay (with `setTimeout` or `HTTP` request...), the value will be emitted after view is initialized, hence `async` pipe already subscribed.

In case of `BehaviorSubject`, when view is initialized, `navbarMenuItems | async` will receive the current value (already emitted during view init), and then explicitly mark view as dirty (need update).

**UPDATE (additional explanation) :**

`OnInit` is called just at the beginning of rendering process. Later `Pipe` directive is binded, and `transform` method is called. During this first called, `AsyncPipe` subscribes to `Observable`.

Hence, `AsyncPipe` subscribes to the `Observable` after `OnInit` is executed.

But in our case, value of `Observable` was already emitted one time.

Comment: So I guess the 'subscription' in this case is when the async pipe is rendered, which happens after I assign the next value?